# Get rid of nested for loops with std::ranges

Tags: c++, nested-loops, c++20, std-ranges

Let I have a code:

```
for (auto& a : x.as)
{
    for (auto& b : a.bs)
    {
        for (auto& c : b.cs)
        {
            for (auto& d : c.ds)
            {
                if (d.e == ..)
                {
                    return ...
                }
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

as, bs, cs, ds - std::vector of corresponding elements.

Is it possible with std::ranges to convert four ugly loops into a beatifull one line expression?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With [`join`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/join_view) and [`transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/transform_view) views, you might do:

```
for (auto& e : x.as | std::views::transform(&A::bs) | std::views::join
                    | std::views::transform(&B::cs) | std::views::join
                    | std::views::transform(&C::ds) | std::views::join
                    | std::views::transform(&D::e))
{
    // ...
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cff2b8ffb942b282)

Comment: why do we have to join after each transform?

Comment: @Timo: To flatten the view: to have `{vectorB1, vectorB2, ..,vectorBN}` into `{B1_1, B1_2, .., B2_1, .. BN_M}`.