# replace nested loops with std::ranges while accessing all contexts

Tags: c++, std-ranges

Lets have a nested loop:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct Account {
    int money;
};

struct Person {
    std::string name;
    std::vector<Account> accounts;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Person> persons;

    for(const auto& iPerson: persons) {
        for(const auto& iAccount: iPerson.accounts) {
            std::cout << iPerson.name << ": " << iAcount.money << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

How could it be replaced with an **std::ranges::view** so that Person and Account are accessible.There is a similar question here: [Get rid of nested for loops with std::ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68405531/get-rid-of-nested-for-loops-with-stdranges). But in this case here a reference to the outer loops person also needed

What I expect is some kind of a tuple of references of the objects from all loop levels

```
auto person_account_view = persons | //...create tuple view;
for(const auto& iPersonAccount: person_account_view) {
    const auto& name = std::get<0>().name;
    const auto& money = std::get<1>().money;
    //do some stuff
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can turn a value into a range with `views::repeat`, and then create a range of tuples with `views::zip`.

```
auto projection = [](auto & person) { return views::zip(views::repeat(person), person.accounts); };
auto person_account_view = persons | views::transform(projection) | views::join;
```

Comment: Great solution. Just be aware that views::zip is available as of C++23 and most compilers only have experimental support for C++23. Additionally I would argue that the original solution with the nested for loop is far easier to read and maintain than the zip/repeat solution. But it does answer the question.

Comment: `::ranges::views::repeat` doesn't accept and `std::views::repeat` can do without the size, as they produce an infinite range, therefore `, person.accounts.size()` can just be wiped out, makeing the code more readable and less redundant.

Comment: @Enlico giving a size means that the zip returns a sized range

Comment: @Caleth, and what's the advantage, here?

Comment: @Enlico I thought `join` might preserve that, but then I looked it up and it doesn't

Answer (score 2):

In C++20 (without zip from C++23), you can "manually" assemble the tuples:

```
  auto make_view = [](Person& p) {
    auto make_tuple = [&p](Account& a) { return std::tie(p, a); };
    return p.accounts | std::views::transform(make_tuple);
  };

  auto person_account_view = persons | std::views::transform(make_view) | std::views::join;
```

You can make the arguments const if you want/need.

(If that's any improvement over the for loops is debatable, but a question for another time.)